# Regex to get last part of url without appended version and parameters

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi guys I've got a very specific request where I would like to get the last part of a url without the parameters but if the name of the script has  a version appended, like -V2, where the 2 could be any number,  the regex would ignore it.

So far I found this `(?!\/)(\w+)(?=.js)` but it is only getting a single word.

Some examples:

https://s3.amazon-aws.com/bob.success.com/scripts/sampleScript-V2.js?x=123&name=bo-b
https://s3.amazon-aws.com/bob.success.com/scripts/sampleScript.js?x=123&name=bo-b
https://s3.amazon-aws.com/bob.success.com/scripts/sampleScript.js
https://s3.amazon-aws.com/bob.success.com/scripts/sampleScript-v2.js

All should match sampleScript

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/\/((.(?!\/))+?)(-v\d|)\.js/i
```

- `\/` matches the character `/`
- 1st Capturing Group `((.(?!\/))+?)`

  - 2nd Capturing Group `(.(?!\/))+?`

    > `.` matches any character
    >
    > `+?` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as
    > few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
    >
    > Negative Lookahead `(?!\/)` Assert that the Regex below does not match : `\/` matches the character `/`
- 3rd Capturing Group `(-v\d|)`

  - 1st Alternative

    > `-v` matches the characters `-v`
    > `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to `[0-9]`)
  - 2nd Alternative

    > `null`, matches any position
- `\.` matches the character `.`
- `js` matches the characters `js`
- Global pattern flags `i` modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of `[a-zA-Z]`)

```js
const urls = [
  'https://s3.amazon-aws.com/bob.success.com/scripts/sampleScript-V2.js?x=123&name=bo-b',
  'https://s3.amazon-aws.com/bob.success.com/scripts/sampleScript.js?x=123&name=bo-b',
  'https://s3.amazon-aws.com/bob.success.com/scripts/sampleScript.js', 
  'https://s3.amazon-aws.com/bob.success.com/scripts/sampleScript-v2.js'
];

const regexp = /\/((.(?!\/))+?)(-v\d|)\.js/i;

urls.forEach(url => console.log(regexp.exec(url)[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use:

```
.*\/((?:(?!-[Vv]\d+\b)[^\s\/])*)\.js\b
```

**Explanation**

- `.*\/` Match till the last occurrence of `/`
- `(` capture group 1

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?!-[Vv]\d+\b)` Assert not `-v` followed by digits to the right
    - `[^\s\/]` Match any non whitespace char except `/`
  - `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
- `)` Close group 1
- `\.js\b` Match `.js` followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tA8CxH/1)

```js
const regex = /.*\/((?:(?!-[Vv]\d+\b)[^\s\/])*)\.js\b/;

[
  "https://s3.amazon-aws.com/bob.success.com/scripts/sampleScript-V2.js?x=123&name=bo-b",
  "https://s3.amazon-aws.com/bob.success.com/scripts/sampleScript.js?x=123&name=bo-b",
  "https://s3.amazon-aws.com/bob.success.com/scripts/sampleScript.js",
  "https://s3.amazon-aws.com/bob.success.com/scripts/sampleScript-v2.js",
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[1]);
  }
})
```

Another option with a lookahead only:

```
 .*\/((?!\w*-[vV]\d+\b)[^\s\/]*)\.js\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TC8Jn5/1)

Answer (score 0):

To match just "sampleScript" in all examples, using a lookahead to match ".js" optionally preceded by "-v" or "-V" and a digit: `(?<=\/)[^/]+(?=(?:-[vV]\d)?\.js)`.

To match the entire file name and extension, just remove the lookahead: `(?<=\/)[^/]+(?:-[vV]\d)?\.js`.

(If the regex can have the `i` flag, you can use v instead of `[vV]`.)